# Rewrite the inject method in ruby

Tags: ruby

How would one go about rewriting the [inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) method but in ruby, basically to have

```
(5..10).inject { |sum, n| sum + n }  == (5..10).new_inject { |sum, n| sum + n }
```

evaluate to `true`. That is without using method_missing...

EDIT:

As requested, this is what I've got so far:

```
module Enumerable
  def new_inject(&block)
    if block_given?
      a ||= self.first
      self[1..-1].each do |s|
        @result = block.call(a,s)
      end
    end
    @result
   end   
end
```

Comment: For summation specifically, or more generally?  Plus, could you show what you've got so far?

Comment: is this just an exercise?  You're trying to recreate inject without using inject?  In your code so far `[1..-1]` will drop the first element, don't know if that's your intention.  Just plain old `each` (no need for self) will iterate over the range.

Comment: @numbers1311407 `[1..-1]` doesn't drop the last element, it excludes the first.

Comment: @dbenhur oops thanks, yeah obviously.  not sure what happened there, my hands disagreed with my brain.

Comment: [1..-1] will actually drop the first element, not the last, i set the first element aside, because [1,2].inject{|a,b| a=10;a+b} will return 12, not 13... yes, it's a personal challenge

Comment: @RobinR.Winton you're on the right track then, but don't forget that inject optionally takes an initial value, and symbols representing methods

Answer (score 3):

Excellent examples of pure Ruby implementations of most of the Ruby stdlib can be found in [Rubinius](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/); here's [`inject`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/enumerable.rb#L266-L300)

In your attempt I spot several mistakes:

1. You don't have the signature of `inject` right, there's four variants.
2. Your assuming that `self` responds_to `:[]` which isn't a promise fullfilled by all `Enumerable`s.
3. You've failed to update your accumulator `a` in your loop.
4. You should use `yield` in preference to `block.call` (it's faster)